# how to animate numbers using Jquery

Tags: jquery, jquery-plugins, jquery-animate

I am trying to animate a say $233 to $250  or decreasing from 250 to 233 ,i dont want to replace 233 by 250 instead i want a counter kind of effect and at the time of scrolling numbers zoom effect is also required.
 i am new to Jquery any help would be highly appreciated.

Comment: What do you mean by scrolling numbers zoom effect?

Comment: at the time of increasing / decreasing the numbers fro 233 to 25o Zoom effect i.e number should be zoomed while the counter is running and it should come to its normal position when counter is finished.

Comment: What do you mean by "zoom effect" on a number, though? Still not clear. Every time the number gets incremented, the font size gets larger?

Comment: say the number has a fontsize of 12px.   so when incrementing this number the font-size should be increased to say 20px and once the counter has finished counting it shoulc come back to its normal 12px font size. is it clear now?

Comment: Yes, much better thanks.

Comment: @Dhirendra: see my edit. Is that what you were looking for?

Answer (score 18, accepted):

#### HTML

```
<button id="start">Start</button>
<button id="reset">Reset</button>
<input id="counter" value="233"/>
```

#### JavaScript

```
$(function ()
{
    var $start = $('#start'),
        start = $start.get(0),
        $reset = $('#reset'),
        reset = $reset.get(0),
        $counter = $('#counter'),
        startVal = $counter.text(),
        currentVal = startVal,
        endVal = 250,
        prefix = '$',
        fontSize = $counter.css('font-size');

    $start.click(function ()
    {
        this.disabled = true;
        var i = setInterval(function ()
        {
            if (currentVal === endVal)
            {
                clearInterval(i);
                reset.disabled = false;
                $counter.animate({fontSize: fontSize});
            }
            else
            {
                currentVal++;
                $counter.text(prefix+currentVal).animate({fontSize: '+=1'}, 100);
            }
        }, 100);
    });

    $reset.click(function ()
    {
        $counter.text(prefix + startVal);
        this.disabled = true;
        start.disabled = false;
    }).click();
});
```

***[Demo →](http://jsfiddle.net/mattball/gGtxL/)***

Comment: @thank's Matt, but i forgot to mention that the it should be either way i.e from 233 to 250 or 250 to 233  depending upon what are initial paramaeters it need to animate in decreasing/increasing order

Comment: If you understand this code, it should be very straightforward to extend it to meet your needs. Since you're new to jQuery, I'd say that would make for an good learning exercise. Give it a try.

Answer (score 16):

Googled this snippet and it looks pretty awesome and compact:

```
// Animate the element's value from 0% to 110%:
jQuery({someValue: 0}).animate({someValue: 110}, {
    duration: 1000,
    easing:'swing', // can be anything
    step: function() { // called on every step
        // Update the element's text with rounded-up value:
        $('#el').text(Math.ceil(this.someValue) + "%");
    }
});
```

[Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/grammakov/Hy3Jv/)

Comment: Mr.Denis.. This is cool but Is there any way to counter on scroll?

Comment: you should add a complete: function() as well or the number will be wrong for fast animations with high values.

Comment: @red thanks, feel free to edit my initial answer dude

Answer (score 4):

@Denis. The second answer has some problem,I change the code as follows:

```
// Animate the element's value from 0% to 110%:
jQuery({someValue: 0}).animate({someValue: 110}, {
    duration: 1000,
    easing:'swing', // can be anything
    step: function(now) { // called on every step
        // Update the element's text with rounded-up value:
        $('#el').text(Math.ceil(now) + "%");
    }
});
```

This will avoid the precision question.

Comment: yes. This is the perfect answer. It fixed the precision issue

Answer (score 2):

The counter is easy, however It's not very clear how you want the effect to look like(give us a link to an example). Regardless the effect would probably be unpractical to do in jQuery.

I would recommend something like [raphael js](http://raphaeljs.com/)

Have a look at the examples, they are very nice.

Answer (score 2):

Here's a fun way to do it with a sort of slot machine effect.

Assuming this simple HTML:

```
<span id="foo">123</span> <!--- number to change --->
<a href="#" id="go">Go!</a> <!--- start the slot machine --->
```

Then:

```
var changeto = 456;

function slotmachine(id) {
    var thisid = '#' + id;
    var $obj = $(thisid);
    $obj.css('opacity', '.3');
    var original = $obj.text();

    var spin = function() {
        return Math.floor(Math.random() * 10);
    };

    var spinning = setInterval(function() {
        $obj.text(function() {
            var result = '';
            for (var i = 0; i < original.length; i++) {
                result += spin().toString();
            }
            return result;
        });
    }, 50);

    var done = setTimeout(function() {
        clearInterval(spinning);
        $obj.text(changeto).css('opacity', '1');
    }, 1000);
}

$('#go').click(function() {
    slotmachine('foo');
});
```

Having the digits "resolve" one by one, movie-codebreaking-style, is left as an exercise.

Example: http://jsfiddle.net/redler/tkG2H/

Answer (score 1):

```
$.fn.increment = function (from, to, duration, easing, complete) {
    var params = $.speed(duration, easing, complete);
    return this.each(function(){
        var self = this;
        params.step = function(now) {
            self.innerText = now << 0;
        };

        $({number: from}).animate({number: to}, params);
    });
};

$('#count').increment(0, 1337);
```

read more: http://www.josscrowcroft.com/2011/code/jquery-animate-increment-decrement-numeric-text-elements-value/

Or without jQuery:

```
function increment(elem, from, to, duration) {    
    var interval = setInterval(function(){
        if (from >= to) clearInterval(interval);        
        elem.innerText = from++;  
    }, duration);
};

increment(document.getElementById("count"), 13, 37, 100);
```

Answer (score 1):

I'd recommend using the odometer javascript plugin for this:
http://github.hubspot.com/odometer/

Answer (score 0):

Untested - but should work along these lines

create the HTML like this:

```
<div>earn $<span id='counter'>233</span> without working hard</div>
```

and jQuery like this:

```
function increment(){
    $('#counter').text(parseFloat($('#counter').text())+1)
    if(parseFloat($('#counter').text()) < 250){ setTimeout(increment,100) }
}
increment()
```