# How to add number with animation

Tags: javascript, jquery

I want to add number in existing number like stopwatch, My function is adding number perfectly but I want to add animation like stopwatch, I tried but I did not get any clue to get it done. Here's a [working demo](http://jsfiddle.net/uyG92/)

```
$('a').click(function() {
    var val = parseInt($(this).text());
    var currentVal = parseInt($('#price').text())
    var cal = parseInt(val-currentVal)
    var club = parseInt($('#price').text()) + cal
    var bb = $('#price').text(club)
})
})​
```

HTML

```
<a href="#">10000</a>
<a href="#">12000</a>
<a href="#">15000</a>
<div id="price">10000</div>
```

Comment: Can you define 'animation like a stopwatch'? Stopwatches I've seen don't have animation, the values just appear.

Comment: Like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4424099/js-jquery-number-increasing-animation and http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5411343/how-to-animate-numbers-using-jquery ?

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan: please see this http://thecodeplayer.com/walkthrough/make-a-stopwatch-using-css3-without-images-or-javascript, you can see value being added

Comment: What's your definition for "adding"? You mean replacing?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use javascript function `setInterval` to do animation of your choice.
[view jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/vusan/uyG92/1/)

have a look about `setInterval` on [javascript animation](http://javascript.info/tutorial/animation) for beginner to advance javascript animation without using any framework.

Answer (score 1):

When you set .text, consider that you can apply JQuery animations here as strings of callbacks. For instance, something like this might work. Change the last line of the function to:

```
$('#price').fadeOut('fast', function() { this.text(club); this.fadeIn('fast');})
```

There's more information with a JSFiddle link to a working example [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6305667/change-text-html-with-animate).